Entity Framework 6 Upgrade to EF Core
I have an existing database which was created with entity framework 6 and code first migrations, this has worked great and includes the default asp.net identity models.
I'm in the process of updating to asp.net core and entity framework core. MY issue is that the identity models have changed during this process but also my old migrations cannot be used anymore.
What I want to do but there doesn't seem to be an easy way is create and initial migration which maps to the existing database. then I could create a 'updateToModels' migration based on my models to make and changes to the core identity models. I think it will add asp_userTokens and change a couple of columns nothing to major, but without the first intial migration of the current database scheme I don't know how to get this working.
Sorry if this is a daft question but I'm relatively inexperienced and have stuggled finding any examples which aren't huge work arounds.
I tried importing the old migrations but they are incompatible, I then tried to create a new initial migration but the tables then don't match the tables in my existing database so the 'update-database' can't run.

You can use EF6 with .NET!

Check this similar question

@ErikEJ the problem seems to be more about the changes in Identity than EF 6 vs EF Core. Does ASP.NET Core 6 work with EF 6?

I suggest you could check this github issue reply, someone the issuer create a migration script to update the database for the asp.net core identity, then you could directly using asp.net core identity with this existing database.
More details, you could refer to this github issue and issuer also share the migrate script. But I suggest you could do it by yourself.
Create a new asp.net core application, then follow its generated model to create the db script to update old database and then you could use it inside the new asp.net core identity project.
